# Copy a file with its original permissions

Tags: c#, copy, file-permissions, file-copying

When using the File.Copy() method the file is copied to its new directory however it loses its original permissions.

Is there a way to copy a file so that it doesn't lose the permissions?

Comment: The file isn't inheriting the parents folders permissions is it?

Comment: If I use File.Copy() none of the permissions is applied to the new file.

Using [Alex's solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9164000/1192774) works.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I believe you can do something like this:

```
const string sourcePath = @"c:\test.txt";
const string destinationPath = @"c:\test2.txt"

File.Copy(sourcePath, destinationPath);

FileInfo sourceFileInfo = new FileInfo(sourcePath);
FileInfo destinationFileInfo = new FileInfo(destinationPath);

FileSecurity sourceFileSecurity = sourceFileInfo.GetAccessControl();
sourceFileSecurity.SetAccessRuleProtection(true, true);
destinationFileInfo.SetAccessControl(sourceFileSecurity);
```

Comment: GetAccessControl is only supported on Windows.

Comment: Proved to work in .NET6 as well (so probably it works in .NET Core also)

Answer (score -1):

Alex's answer, updated for .NET Core 3.1 (actually most .NET):

```
var sourceFileInfo = new FileInfo(sourcePath);
var destinationFileInfo = new FileInfo(destinationPath);
// Copy the file
sourceFileInfo.CopyTo(destinationPath, true); // allow overwrite of the destination
// Update the file attributes
destinationFileInfo.Attributes = sourceFileInfo.Attributes
```

Comment: Does not work for access rights.